# R readr package - written and read in file doesn't match source

Tags: r, readr

I apologize in advance for the somewhat lack of reproducibility here. I am doing an analysis on a very large (for me) dataset. It is from the [CMS Open Payments database](https://www.cms.gov/openpayments/).

There are four files I downloaded from that website, read into R using `readr`,  then manipulated a bit to make them smaller (column removal), and then stuck them all together using `rbind`. I would like to write my pared down file out to an external hard drive so I don't have to read in all the data each time I want to work on it and doing the paring then. (Obviously, its all scripted but, it takes about 45 minutes to do this so I'd like to avoid it if possible.)

So I wrote out the data and read it in, but now I am getting different results. Below is about as close as I can get to a good example. The data is named `sa_all`. There is a column in the table for the source. It can only take on two values: `gen` or `res`. It is a column that is actually added as part of the analysis, not one that comes in the data.

```
 table(sa_all$src)

 gen      res 
14837291   822559
```

So I save the `sa_all` dataframe into a CSV file.

```
write.csv(sa_all, 'D:\\Open_Payments\\data\\written_files\\sa_all.csv',
      row.names = FALSE)
```

Then I open it:

```
sa_all2 <- read_csv('D:\\Open_Payments\\data\\written_files\\sa_all.csv')

table(sa_all2$src)

g      gen      res 
1 14837289   822559
```

I did receive the following parsing warnings.

```
Warning: 4 parsing failures.
row        col           expected        actual
5454739 pmt_nature                    embedded null
7849361 src        delimiter or quote 2            
7849361 src                           embedded null
7849361 NA         28 columns         54 columns
```

Since I manually add the `src` column and it can only take on two values, I don't see how this could cause any parsing errors.

Has anyone had any similar problems using `readr`? Thank you.

---

Just to follow up on the comment:

```
write_csv(sa_all, 'D:\\Open_Payments\\data\\written_files\\sa_all.csv')
sa_all2a <- read_csv('D:\\Open_Payments\\data\\written_files\\sa_all.csv')
Warning: 83 parsing failures.
    row   col   expected        actual
1535657 drug2            embedded null
1535657 NA    28 columns 25 columns   
1535748 drug1            embedded null
1535748 year  an integer No           
1535748 NA    28 columns 27 columns
```

Even more parsing errors and it looks like some columns are getting shuffled entirely:

```
table(sa_all2a$src)

         100000000278         Allergan Inc.                   gen GlaxoSmithKline, LLC. 
                    1                     1              14837267                     1 
                   No                   res 
                    1                822559
```

There are columns for manufacturer names and it looks like those are leaking into the `src` column when I use the `write_csv` function.

Comment: Why not use the same package `readr` to write and read the file? `readr::write_csv()` may work better with `readr::read_csv()`. Or stick with `utils`... `utils::write.csv()` and `utils::read.csv()`

Comment: Thank you, @cory. I also tried the `read_csv()` method from `readr` with the same results. I don't think I can use the `read.csv` function because the file size is around 3GB even once it is pared down.

Comment: Are you ensuring that the data is quoted and that if there are quotes in the data, they are escaped properly. It looks like the embedded commas and the default handling of them, may be a problem.

Comment: I am not certain. Looking at the documentation for `write.csv`, I see there is a default argument `quote = TRUE`. Is this what you are referring to?